How to repair initramfs-tools because it errors out with every single apt change?
sudo apt-get auto-remove && apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic (6.2.0-36.37~22.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/acr/ucode_ahesasc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/acr/ucode_ahesasc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/acr/ucode_ahesasc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/acr/ucode_ahesasc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/acr/ucode_ahesasc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/acr/ucode_asb.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/acr/ucode_asb.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/acr/ucode_asb.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/acr/ucode_asb.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/acr/ucode_asb.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/gr/NET_img.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/gr/NET_img.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/gr/NET_img.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/gr/NET_img.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/gr/NET_img.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/sec2/hs_bl_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/sec2/hs_bl_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/sec2/hs_bl_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/sec2/hs_bl_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/sec2/hs_bl_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-1
I: (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptkeyctl failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic (6.2.0-36.37~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/acr/ucode_ahesasc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/acr/ucode_ahesasc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/acr/ucode_ahesasc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/acr/ucode_ahesasc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/acr/ucode_ahesasc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/acr/ucode_asb.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/acr/ucode_asb.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/acr/ucode_asb.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/acr/ucode_asb.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/acr/ucode_asb.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/gr/NET_img.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/gr/NET_img.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/gr/NET_img.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/gr/NET_img.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/gr/NET_img.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/sec2/hs_bl_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/sec2/hs_bl_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/sec2/hs_bl_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/sec2/hs_bl_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/sec2/hs_bl_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-1
I: (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptkeyctl failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

This has beeng going on for months. My Ubuntu kind of works, but I've found out it does not actually use my GPU. So I've gone around in circles trying to update the driver and it doesn't.
My history is I had put my kernels on hold because one of the updates bootloop failed it so I had to use a rescue kernel and then delete the broken kernel. Whatever, I guess I am ready to fight through that fight.
I have since unheld them and restarted half a dozen times troubleshooting my other issues and I can't get anywhere.
For the last several months every time I did an apt get install or anything like that, it would complain that the initramfs had an error and wouldn't udpate my linux image. But any apps I chose to install seemed to work just fine.
Also of note is I have LUKS encrypted every ubuntu partition in the dual boot system. Ubuntu does not play well with encryption from what I can see, and doing things like a clean install of Ubuntu having LUKS encryption is impossible without data loss.
So what steps can I take to get initramfs-tools to actually work? And as such, be able to uninstall my nvidia drivers to start fresh?
The nvidia module nouveau stuff is an aside to be taken care of once I can figure out why initramfs always fails and I can install a good driver for nvidia. HEre is an example of how my updates of any app have gone in the past few months (with the module nouveau errors removed from the log as those are new today.)
$ sudo apt remove gpaint
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libglade2-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gpaint
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 728 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 289144 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gpaint (0.3.3-6.1build2) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic (6.2.0-36.37~22.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/acr/ucode_ahesasc.bin for module nouveau
...
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-1
I: (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptkeyctl failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic (6.2.0-36.37~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/acr/ucode_ahesasc.bin for module nouveau
...
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-1
I: (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptkeyctl failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
user:/$ sudo apt install gpaint
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gpaint
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 120 kB of archives.
After this operation, 728 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 gpaint amd64 0.3.3-6.1build2 [120 kB]
Fetched 120 kB in 3s (47.3 kB/s) 
Selecting previously unselected package gpaint.
(Reading database ... 289114 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gpaint_0.3.3-6.1build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gpaint (0.3.3-6.1build2) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic (6.2.0-36.37~22.04.1) ...
Setting up gpaint (0.3.3-6.1build2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/acr/ucode_ahesasc.bin for module ...
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-1
I: (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptkeyctl failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic (6.2.0-36.37~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/acr/ucode_ahesasc.bin for module nouveau
...
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-1
I: (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptkeyctl failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


Got it!
Just go into /usr/share/initiramfs-tools/hooks and edit (sudo nano) the cryptkeyctl file and comment out the lines
#copy_exec /lib/cryptsetup/askpass
#copy_exec /bin/keyctl

Far as I can tell from a cursor search of what copy_exec does, it's not important. Other example files like at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560755 don't even have that as part of the file. Once I commented out those lines, the initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic in /boot finally updated.

Note, this will break the crypt setup and it will refuse to accept your correct password. Instead it tries to cache it and then talks about failure to add to the keyring. But all in all, the initramfs can finally update without error, even if the system becomes useless afterward.

Better answer. It looks like I was entirely missing the /bin/keyctl file. I managed to find it in my trash/expunged with a search in nautilus at the / directory. Oddly, it was homed in /usr/bin initially.  It's the same name, probably the same file, so I restored that to /bin folder and I was able to compile an initimg without complaint. Just a matter of rebooting to make sure crypt isn't broken.
